# How to make a mocked method return the same mock

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a class that contain a `clone` method. I want the clone to return the same mock :

```
when(regressor.cloneWithSharedResources()).thenReturn(regressor);
```

However, this returns me a different object. Is there a convenient way to do that ?

Comment: How does it look when you create the mocked instance? Is the method "cloneWithSharedResources" actually being called? What kind of object is returned instead? The code that you have provided looks about right to me.

Comment: That's a mock, so the actual method will never be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've misuderstood something about your question because I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour.

I've created a simple test to reproduce it:

```
public class FooTest {
   class Regressor {
      public Regressor cloneWithSharedResources() {
         return new Regressor();
      }
   }

   class ClassToTest {
      public Regressor foo(Regressor regressor) {
         // ...
         return regressor.cloneWithSharedResources();
      }
   }

   @Test
   public void testFoo() throws Exception {
      Regressor regressor = Mockito.mock(Regressor.class);
      Mockito.when(regressor.cloneWithSharedResources()).thenReturn(regressor);

      ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest();
      Regressor clonedRegressor = classToTest.foo(regressor);

      Assert.assertSame(regressor, clonedRegressor);
   }
}
```

This test passes successfully, so `regressor` and `clonedRegressor` are actually the same object.

Please, could you tell me if I'm wrong or I've misunderstooed something. Hope it helps.

*NOTE*: I've tested with `Mockito 1.9.4`

Comment: Sorry, cannot answer right now, I'll check later, thanks for the answer

Comment: Turns out I was not calling `Mockito.verify` on the mock I thought. This mock was itself returned by another mock, and I screwed up the (overloaded) signature of the method supposed to be called and return it. As a result, I was returned a different mock, breaking my assumptions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to give same object. Can you post your code. i have tried below code and it gives me the same object.

```
t = mock(Tester.class);
when(t.clone()).thenReturn(t);
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot answer right now, I'll check later, thanks for the answer